# 1 WAN ways to switch between different routers to change IP address

Tags: networking, router, ip, wan

I have 1 ethernet cable from my ISP, when I plug that cable to a different router and the IP address will be changed (IP wont change when I re-plug into the same router). So now I have bought lots of router, in order to change the IP address frequently. The problem is, how can I set it up so that the cable WAN will be connected to "something" and that something will be connected to all routers I bought, so that I can switch (turning on only 1 router at each time) between different routers through, maybe turning off in "somethings" in the router admin page?

2 questions. Do I need "somethings" like bridge/switcher/hub? How do I control which router the WAN to pointing to, by turning off "DHCP" in the router admin page or something else ??

Comment: How is the connection presented - is it ethernet?  Please delete your question from Stackoverflow.

Comment: The address is _not_ a static address unless you manually configure it in your router. I explained this the last time you posted this question.

Comment: I think what is happening is that your ISP is assigning an address based on the MAC address of your router. You could probably achieve the same result by changing the MAC address of your router and having it renew from DHCP.

Comment: I'm worried that you think that by frequently changing your IP address, you can keep the government censors from figuring out that it is you. That is not going to work; the ISP will always know that it is you, and it can tell the government who and where you are.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong solution. What you need to find out is how to automate the process of changing the MAC address of your router's WAN interface. Using multiple routers isn't the way to go here. Also, your post needs some cleanup. Don't use 'etc.' and unnecessary punctuations -- they don't make it easier for readers to parse and understand your post.

Comment: Note that traditionally, posts which start with `0 down vote favorite` are created  by bots with faulty parsers.

Comment: @FrankThomas, that is not a bot. We carried on a conversation about this the last time this was posted. This is in China,

Comment: I will try the suggested solution first. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

> So now I have bought lots of router, in order to change the IP address
>   frequently.

Poor approach I'm afraid.

IPs are binding to MAC addresses, as different routers have different MACs you get different addresses. But you dont need to change router to change MAC, many routers can MAC Spoof meaning one router can do the job of your current collection of many.

As a side note, you really shouldnt need to change your WAN IP regularly unless you're doing something nefarious.